# Value not getting removed from Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to remove some value stored at a particular reference on Firebase. Here's how I have stored it:

```
mDatabase.child("users").child(uid).child("followersUID").child(itemIDFU).setValue(MainActivity.uid);
```

Here's how I'm trying to remove it:

```
mDatabase.child("users").child(uid).child("followersUID").child(itemIDFU).child(MainActivity.uid).removeValue();
```

`itemIDFU` has been generated in `onCreate()` using this code:

```
itemIDFU = mDatabase.child("users").child(uid).push().getKey();
```

The problem is that it is getting stored successfully, but not getting removed. What's going wrong here? Please let me know.

Comment: Please paste the Firebase json that you received.

Comment: @AndresVasquezAgramont please tell me more clearly what I am supposed to do? Thanks.

Comment: @HammadNasir If you can, go to your database console where it shows your data. On the top right corner you will see the three dots. Click it and choose "Export JSON". Then take a screenshot of the data area we are working with. This way we can see if the JSON format is the issue (this is a common issue when working with Firebase).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like when you set the value, you set the key `itemIDFU` to equal whatever value is in `MainActivity.uid`

However, when you delete the data, you are trying to get the ***child*** of `itemIDFU`, which doesn't exist.

You didn't add `MainActivity.uid` as the ***child*** of `itemIDFU`, you added it as the ***value***.

**You have two possible solutions:**

Try this if you want to remove the value, but leave the `itemIDFU` key there empty:

```
mDatabase.child("users").child(uid).child("followersUID").child(itemIDFU).setValue(null);
```

Try this if you want to completely remove the key and value:

```
mDatabase.child("users").child(uid).child("followersUID").child(itemIDFU).removeValue();
```

**Here is a picture to help illustrate the data and the problem:**

[image]

**One more picture to explain**

[image]

Comment: @HammadNasir Good, I am glad it is working! Firebase is such a useful API. My personal favorite!

Comment: @HammadNasir Will just add to explanation of issue. Bro, when you set a value to child. **It can't be referred as a child**. Remember firebase saves data as key-value pairs. So every child becomes a **key** and value becomes **vaue for that key**. Just remember this and you will avoid such errors later.

Comment: well, it hasn't solved the problem though... it is getting removed when removing at that time only but when I'm exiting app and then opening the profile again the value isn't getting removed!

Comment: @HammadNasir When the onCreate() is called and you push() your new value into the Database, you will get a  new unique ID every time. If you leave the app, however, and come back later trying to delete the old information you will not be able to because that unique ID (itemIDFU) will be something different. Unless you store that key in some persistent storage (like sharedpreferences) or in the database in another list somewhere, you will have no way to delete it.

Comment: @Ryan that's why I mentioned `itemIDFU = mDatabase.child("users").child(uid).push().getKey();` can be causing this issue. I think the solution lies in persistence data storage no doubt. To keep track of old push ids.

Comment: Yes I do believe that this is the issue. I think you do understand the problem. Now you need to figure out if you want to continue pushing that data and having unique key value every time, or if you want to make your own ID (like using update() instead and passing it the itemIDFU as the key). If you choose to stay with the current push() and unique ID then you will have no choice but to store and track all those IDs. If you do not HAVE to have the unique ID, consider changing the way you structure the data to allow for a key based on information you already have (like the itemIDFU itself).

Comment: I apologize, I meant setValue(), not update(). update() is for web, not Android. I must say that this question is a bit beyond the scope of the original issue which I do believe has been solved (deleting the value). As for restructuring your database to allow for a pre-known key, that is a whole project in itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove values in these two ways:

**//first way to remove a value**

```
mDatabase.child("users").child(uid).child("followersUID").child(itemIDFU).setValue(null);
```

**//or try this**

```
mDatabase.child("users").child(uid).child("followersUID").child(itemIDFU).removeValue();
```

*I feel that the value is not getting removed as you are adding .removeValue() on value of child rather than child itself.*

Comment: He really isn't calling removeValue() on any value at all since the value he is trying to call it on is on a child that doesn't exist. The child "MainActivity.uid" does not exist, and as such, has no value. But none the less, your solution (same as mine) solves the problem.

Comment: @HammadNasir are you saying that neither answer is working?

Comment: @Ryan I simply mean that he is using his **value for a child** to call .removeValue . Which is indeed same to your explanation. But am not really trying to post any wrong info. Sorry for bad conversation skills if I couldn't explain it well enough :)

Comment: No need to apologize Hammad. So have you been able to remove the value that you are trying to remove?

Comment: @Ryan I just meant that .child(MainActivity.uid).removeValue(); has **MainActivity.uid as the value of child(itemIDFU) so he should have used the actual child** hope I explain myself better here.

Comment: @HammadNasir can you please post your complete java code as well ? I think there is some error in your other implementation and not just this bit.

Comment: I am a bit confused, sorry. Do you understand that .child(MainActivity.uid) doesn't exist? Your code never created a child with that. If you are trying to get a child with the MainActivity.uid value you are never going to find it. So your second line where you try to remove it is never going to work, because you are trying to remove something that isn't there. Take a close look at my picture and you will see that itemIFDU doesn't have a child at all, yet, your code is trying to remove it's child.

Comment: I agree with @Ryan . Hammad please share your java code too because you might be doing something wrong here as well `itemIDFU = mDatabase.child("users").child(uid).push().getKey();` . I just wanna know how exactly you are using this. If while removing you are also executing this code then you will get different itemIDFU due to usage of  **.push()** which will never get you to desired database ref.

Comment: @HammadNasir I added one more picture to my post to try to explain what I mean. I hope this helps.

Comment: @NIshantDubey bro, I have called `itemIDFU = mDatabase.child("users").child(uid).push().getKey();` only in `onCreate()`.